Getting error "Original error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent. Original error: xcodebuild failed with code 70."
Appium server is already running , still getting following error while trying to establish connection :
"Failed to create session. An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent. Original error: xcodebuild failed with code 70. This usually indicates an issue with the local Xcode setup or WebDriverAgent project configuration or the driver-to-platform version mismatch. Consider checking the WebDriverAgent configuration guide for real iOS devices at https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md.. Make sure you follow the tutorial at https://appium.github.io/appium-xcuitest-driver/latest/preparation/real-device-config/ "
please help if anyone has encountered this error before. Screenshot attached.
I am in process of doing Mobile app automation using Appium and expecting a successful connection with my real device and simulator.

The error is telling you how to fix it, probably you didnt follow the tutorial in the link. You need to open webdriveragent with xcode and change provisioning profile as in the tutorial.
